# REST API ItemCount on oData BCS List

Tags: development, javascript, sharepoint-online, bcs, odata

I have a list generated from a BCS oData provider and I am attempting to get the number of items in the list so I can generate a $top on my request rather than bring back only the 100 item generic limit.

I am trying the following query in the cross-domain SP javascript, but it returns 0 items.

Any advice?

```
executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url: appweburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Vendors')/itemcount", method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: countSuccessHandler,
                error: errorHandler
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you might not be able to retrieve accurate count because of the nature of the BCS queries which only return a Maximum of 2000 records normally. I would recommend you read this article http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9628.sharepoint-2010-row-limits-in-external-lists.aspx

Also one other potential way to read that information could be to create a custom read operation to call a stored procedure (if that is feasible).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this endpoint url,

```
https://<site url>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/<List Name>/$count
```

Comment: This end point URL does not work list with items more than 5000 items.